# Prestashop: How to update themes and modules manually?

Tags: module, themes, prestashop, upgrade, prestashop-1.7

Some modules can be auto-updated in backoffice by clicking the update button. However if the module is from an other source than prestashop itself (e.g. github) the module needs - afaik - to be updated manually.

So how should one handle updates?

Download ZIP and

1. `unzip` it over the corresponding modules folder (`/modules/acme/`)
2. unzip and `rsync` it to `/modules/acme` (`rsync -trv /tmp/acme /modules`)
3. Same as 2 but with `--delete`
4. Delete the folder completely and unzip the new one in place like `rm -rf /modules/acme` and `cp -a /tmp/acme /modules/acme`
5. Others ...

Side note: what about the config.xml and possibly other generated files?

Same applies for theme updates, how to handle these?

Concerning current version Prestashop 1.7+.

Answer (score 1):

If the module upgrade is made correctly (you can check if module version is updated in main module class constructor and uses upgrade scripts in `upgrades` folder and files inside the module) you can unzip over it. Then visit the modules list page in backend and module upgrade will run. `config.xml` is auto (re)generated and used only for optimizing module list loading in the same backend page - it has no effect on module behaviour itself.

For themes you can also just unzip over the last one.

When I am in doubt with any upgrades I make a development copy of the store and do upgrades there first and see if everything is ok then do upgrades on live instance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Of course I have a local and beta and a production setup running. But it's great to get some experience from other devs like you :) What about depreciated (or auto generated) files? Example: the ingenico module has some files in v4.0.0 hat are a) eighter auto generated or b) removed from v4.0.1. If a) unzipping over is just fine. If b) I could delete the depreciated files (`rsync --delete`).

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the upgrade automatically with this free module
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/

Hope it helps